# MYSQL PHP PDO Fill table with database data

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to give out a  for every line in my database.
It seems that it is working but only returns the first column.

[image: screenshot]
**Note: There are values for the empty fields in database!**

```
$columns = "Ticket, Last_Modified_Date, Requester";
```

Heres my code:

```
    function getTicket($columns){
    echo($columns);
    global $db_host, $db_name, $db_user, $db_pass;
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;charset=utf8", "$db_user", "$db_pass");
    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT $columns FROM tickets");
if ($result->execute()){
    echo("<b>Successfully!</b><br><br>");

    $rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $col_names = explode(',', $columns);
foreach($rows as $row){
    echo("<tr>");
foreach($col_names as $col_name){
if (!isset($row[$col_name])){
    continue;
    }
    echo("<td>".$row[$col_name]."</td>");
    }
    echo("</tr>");
        }
    }
else{
    echo("<b>FAILED!</b><br><br>");
    }
    $db = null;
}
```

Comment: PS. Its a bit naughty changing the question after you have received answers. It makes the answers look like nonsence! Its ok to add information that helps to get an answer, but not change it to the extent that its basically a different question.

Comment: If you click on edited you see the changelog and the basic question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues here, first you should use `->fetchall()` which will return ALL the result rows in one hit into an array.

Second you are overwriting your $result statement handle with the row being returned by `->fetch`

```
function getTicket($columns){ 

    global $db_host, $db_name, $db_user, $db_pass;

    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name;charset=utf8", "$db_user", "$db_pass");

    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT $columns FROM tickets");

    if ($result->execute()){
        echo("<b>Successfully!</b><br><br>");

        // CHANGES HERE
        $rows = $result->fetchall(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        $col_names = explode(',', $columns);  //make array of csv

        foreach($rows as $row){

            foreach( $col_names as $col_name ) {
                echo '<td>' . $row[$col_name] . '</td>';
            }
        }
    }else{
        echo("<b>FAILED!</b><br><br>");
    }
    $db = null;
}
```

Comment: Notice: undefined index: column_name

Comment: Yes... I dont know what your column names are as you pass them in a variable and you dont tell us what that may look like

Comment: in this case they are: "Ticket, Last_Modified_Date, Requester"

Comment: Well now you need to write something to make that comma delimited string usable to make those column names available to be used in your output phase

Comment: maybe a foreach or loop to echo every time for each column names?

Comment: Yeah outputs first column "Ticket". But the others are empty... See question at top

Comment: Ok rather than doing nothing in the `isset` test put out some indication that the column was empty. See amendment. Or maybe dont bother doing the `isset` test at all

Comment: yeah, this was a really intelligent hint. Now I see, that every field is filled but only Ticket has value. The others have N/A. Means that there is a problem with getting the variables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81627/discussion-between-riggsfolly-and-maurize).

Answer (score 1):

`->fetch()` returns only one value of the rows.

Use `->fetchAll()` ( [PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.fetchall.php) ) if you want to return all of your results.

Comment: Why it does not work? You're currently using fetch() and you want to have all of your results displayed, what stops you from using fetchAll() ?

Comment: Okay, so if I use fetchAll(), how can I echo line per line without entering for example $result("NAME"); ? I don't know which columns are called in this function because they passed from another function.

Comment: You can echo it the same way as you do right now. All you have to do is loop through an array of results. Right now you echo $value directly, but if you have multiple entries fetchAll() will give you an array which looks different. Check your $value with var_dump() and you'll see the difference.

Comment: Okay Astinox you're right. But i cannot echo the output cause its array. So I have to foreach or something..

Comment: Instead of echo you can use either var_dump() or print_r() to get the value of an array.